# Regex Match when there shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok, I have some experience with regex, but I use them regularly for simple pattern matching, I am doing this in JS, I have two patterns to find, "POA1234" and "PO1234" the PO will always be there, the difference is in one instance there is an additional arbitrary alpha after the PO but in both cases the rest is numeric.

So I tried `/^PO\w{1}\d+$/` and it matches "PO1234"? Is not the single extra alpha now required? If someone could explain why this is a match and suggest the fix I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F%5EPO%5Cw%7B1%7D%5Cd%2B%24%2F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I tried `/^PO\w{1}\d+$/` and it matches "PO1234"? Is not the single
>   extra alpha now required?

Well, there are a few points here:

- Your pattern matches "PO1234" because `\w` matches a word character (which means any *alphanumeric* character or underscore).
- `{1}` is redundant. For example, `a` is equal to `a{1}`.
- You don't actually need two patterns. You can just use:

  ```
  ^PO[a-zA-Z]?\d+$
  ```

---

### References:

- [Character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
- [Optional items](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Answer (score 0):

\w is a word character which is [a-zA-Z0-9] so it matches the first digit actually. Instead, change \w to [A-Z]

Comment: Sorry didn't no 0-9 was in "word Characters" thanks

Comment: No problem! {1} is also superfluous here but it can help readability for some people without harming performance